# Include the Windows Event Log in UWF exclusions

Tags: windows, event-log, uwf

I need to track unexpected restarts of an industrial system that uses UWF in Windows 10 LTSC, but I noticed that the Logs are cleaned when the system restarts, leaving only the last ones recorded when UWF was disabled.

How can I include the Windows Event Log in UWF exclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... Just add the exclusions to the paths below:

```
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\assembly"
```